# What are the drawbacks of using a bitnami stack in production?

Tags: stack, production-environment, bitnami

Are there any known drawbacks of using a bitnami stack (lamp, alfresco, ...) in a production area?
please list anything like security issues, non compliance to best practices, ...

Answer (score 3):

To my concern, there are no known drawbacks regarding what you mention. Revisions for all stacks are released shortly after security issues arise, practically as fast as images can be uploaded to cloud providers. Their stacks structure is quite standard, so the issues or doubts you may have are probably already answered out there, for another stack (full compatibility). They are open to feedback, so, in cases of no compliance to best practices, tasks are created and the stack is re-released with the mentioned changes applied. 
Not to forget the fact (that rarely anyone remembers) that the stacks are totally SELF contained. No changes are performed in the system. That means that you could perfectly compress a stack in one computer, decompress that in another and it would still have 100% workability.

Of course, while using them you may found issues. The community forum is intended to collect all the mentioned feedback and answer users who find issues while using stacks, and we do our best to take care of this.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention that I work at Bitnami and I do know the way things are done here ^^. I am open to questions in case you have any other doubt!